# Adiabatic invariant and Liouville's theorem

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, adiabatic

It appears that many people have tried to show [adiabatic theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_invariant) from [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28Hamiltonian%29), e.g., [Li's note](http://li.mit.edu/A/Papers/98/invariant.pdf), or at least tried to find some relations, e.g., [Rugh](http://arxiv.org/abs/nlin/0201062), [Adib](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0205237) and [Tong's lecture notes Sec. 4.6.1 page 116](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/dynamics/clas.pdf).  Can this be done rigorously?  I am particularly interested in the classical (possibly statistical) mechanics sense.  Thank you in advance!

---

Below are some random observations that may or may not be helpful in addressing the question.

### Adiabatic invariant and bulk entropy

An interesting observation is that the bulk entropy in statistical mechanics is an adiabatic invariant.
In quantum mechanics, the integral of [adiabatic invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_invariant) roughly gives the quantum number and the Planck constant, $2 \, \pi \, \hbar$.
\begin{align}
2 \, \pi \, J
&= \oint p \, dq \\
&= (n + \delta) \, 2 \, \pi \, \hbar,
\end{align}
where, $\delta$ is around $1/2$.
For an almost closed system,
since the quantum number $n$ can be written as a function of energy $E$ as $n(E)$,
the adiabatic invariant $J$ is also a function of energy $E$.

This means that the adiabatic invariant $J(E)/\hbar$ gives the number of states $\Omega(E)$ with energy no greater than $E$, and this number is a constant.
Generally, it is shown by Hertz ([article 1](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k153366/f237.item) and [article 2](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k153366/f549.item)) that the phase-space volume enclosed by the energy surface is an adiabatic constant, a fact [appreciated](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0205237) by [Einstein](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k15337j/f189.image.r=).  In this [demonstration](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k153366/f549.item), Hertz used [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28Hamiltonian%29).

Now in statistical mechanics, $\Omega(E)$ is the bulk density of states[1],
and it is related to the usual surface density of states $\omega(E) = e^{ S(E)/k_B }$ as
\begin{align}
\omega(E) = \frac{ \partial \Omega(E) } { \partial E } \Delta E.
\end{align}
So we may say the bulk density of states, or the bulk entropy, is an adiabatic invariant.  This is, I suppose, why in thermodynamics, we say that in a reversible adiabatic process, the entropy change is zero, $dS = 0$ (or no heat is absorbed or released $dQ = 0$).  According to Hertz and Rugh, we are referring to the bulk entropy.

#### Hertz and Rugh's proof of adiabatic invariance of the bulk entropy

The classical version is given in [Hertz](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k153366/f549.item), the modern version is presented in [Rugh](http://arxiv.org/abs/nlin/0201062).

The basic argument is the following. Recall from definition,
$\Omega(E) = \int \Theta(E - H(p,q, \lambda)) \, dp \, dq$, and
$\omega(E) = \Delta E \, \int \delta(E - H(p,q, \lambda)) \, dp \, dq$.
Then
\begin{align}
d \Omega(E, \lambda)
&= (\partial \Omega/\partial E) \, dE + (\partial \Omega/\partial \lambda) d\lambda \\
&= \omega(E) \, dE - \omega(E) \langle \partial H/\partial \lambda \rangle_E d\lambda,
\end{align}

If $\lambda$ is changed slowly, then the time average
  $\overline{ dE/d\lambda } = \overline{ \partial H/ \partial \lambda }$
  should match the phase space average $\langle \partial H/\partial \lambda \rangle_E$
  over the isoenergetic shell, and the right-hand side vanishes.

### References

Hans Henrik Rugh, A Micro-Thermodynamic Formalism,
  [nlin/0201062](http://arxiv.org/abs/nlin/0201062).

A. Adib. Adiabatic invariance with first integrals of motion,
  [cond-mat/0205237](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0205237).

P. Hertz, [Ann Phys. (Leipzig) 33, 225 (1910)](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k153366/f237.item).

P. Hertz, [Ann Phys. (Leipzig) 33, 537 (1910)](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k153366/f549.item).
  Particularly pages 546 to 548.
  Notations differences:
  energy: $E \rightarrow \varepsilon$;
  parameter: $\lambda \rightarrow a$;
  Bulk density of states: $\Omega \rightarrow V$;
  surface density of states, $\omega \rightarrow \omega$;
  breadth of the energy shell, $\Delta E \rightarrow d\nu \sim \Delta E/|\nabla E|$.

A. Einstein, [Ann. Phys. (Leipzig) 34, 175 (1911)](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k15337j/f189.image.r=).

[1] 
Some people define $k_B \log \Omega(E)$ as the “bulk entropy”,
and this leads to some interesting debate, such as [Dunkel and Hilbert](http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v10/n1/full/nphys2815.html) and [Frenkel and Warren](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.4299).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is related to the geometric interpretation of adiabatic invariant in phase space. You can find one-dimensional case in Landau Vol.1, and more general case in Vladimir Arnold's mechanics, sec.38.

Liouville's theorem states that the phase volume is a constant, here the phase volume corresponds to the adiabatic invariant.
For 1D case, the integral $\oint p d q$ (adiabatic invariant) is performed along a closed curve, which is nothing else but the area surrounded by that curve, i.e., $\int d p d q$ -- 2D phase volume.